# How to load a transformed XML (based on a XSL stylesheet) using Java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, nginx, rtmp

I don't understand why the XSL stylesheet isn't applied when I use Java's urlConnection.getInputStream() method.

I'm using [nginx RTMP module rtmp_stat directive](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#statistics). When I access "/stat" using a browser (ie. Firefox) I can get the transformed result.

However, **when access the same URL "/stat" using urlConnection.getInputStream() I actually get the raw XML (before transformation). Why?**

I need to programatically get the transformed result directly from the web server, ie. by simply accessing "/stat". just like the result I get when I use a web browser to access. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting `getInputStream()` to look at the media type, work out that it's XML, parse the XML, discover that there is an `<?xml-stylesheet?>` processing instruction, fetch the stylesheet, apply it, and return the result?

Wishful thinking, I'm afraid.

If you want to run transformations on the server you'll need to implement some server-side code to achieve it. There may be server-side frameworks where you can just set a switch to achieve this, but it's not going to happen by default.